# Расположение картинок html + css

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять как расположить данные блоки

Пробовал через width calc, display:inline-block, ничего не получается и ужасно едет в мобильной версии

```css
.dv-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 330px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.dv-about___button {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dv-ban__img {
  width: 100%;
}

.dv_ban_main {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.first_left_block {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}

.first_left_block img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.first_right_block {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: calc(52% - 21px);
}

.right_item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sad_first_item_img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.sad_second_item_img {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.sad_third_item_img {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sad_thourth_item_img {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dv-wrapper">
  <div class="dv_ban first_block">
    <div class="dv_ban first_left_block">
      <a href="#"><img alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/S7YY64G/sad-lending-2-08-290228.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="dv_ban first_right_block">
      <div class="dv_ban right_item">
        <a href="#"><img class="sad_first_item_img" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/PZhySXN/sad-lending-2-19595473.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="dv_ban right_item">
        <a href="#"><img class="sad_second_item_img" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/PZhySXN/sad-lending-2-19595473.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="dv_ban right_item">
        <a href="#"><img class="sad_third_item_img" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/PZhySXN/sad-lending-2-19595473.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="dv_ban right_item">
        <a href="#"><img class="sad_thourth_item_img" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/PZhySXN/sad-lending-2-19595473.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```css
.blocks {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.blocks:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
.top-wrap,
.bottom-wrap{
  display: flex;
}
.top-right-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.top-left,
.top-right,
.bottom-right{
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.top-left:before,
.top-right:before,
.bottom-center:before,
.bottom-right:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
.bottom-left,
.bottom-center-wrap{
  width: 25%;
}
.bottom-left:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 250%;
}
.bottom-center-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.bottom-center {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .top-wrap,
  .bottom-wrap{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .top-left,
  .top-right-wrap,
  .bottom-right{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .top-right,
  .bottom-left,
  .bottom-center-wrap{
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top-wrap">
  <div class="blocks top-left"></div>
  <div class="top-right-wrap">
    <div class="blocks top-right"></div>
    <div class="blocks top-right"></div>
    <div class="blocks top-right"></div>
    <div class="blocks top-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom-wrap">
  <div class="blocks bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="bottom-center-wrap">
    <div class="blocks bottom-center"></div>
    <div class="blocks bottom-center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocks bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, мобильную версию все таки сверстал отдельно

Answer (score -2):

```html
<div class="dv-wrapper">
<div class="dv_ban first_block">
<div class="dv_ban first_left_block"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/S7YY64G/sad-lending-2-08-290228.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="dv_ban first_right_block">
<div class="dv_ban right_item"><a href="#"><img class="sad_first_item_img" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/PZhySXN/sad-lending-2-19595473.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="dv_ban right_item"><a href="#"><img class="sad_second_item_img" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/PZhySXN/sad-lending-2-19595473.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="dv_ban right_item"><a href="#"><img class="sad_third_item_img" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/PZhySXN/sad-lending-2-19595473.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="dv_ban right_item"><a href="#"><img class="sad_thourth_item_img" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/PZhySXN/sad-lending-2-19595473.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
.dv_ban.first_block {
    display: flex;
}
.dv_ban.first_left_block img, .right_item img {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.dv_ban.first_left_block img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.first_left_block {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
}
.first_right_block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.right_item {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Нужно расставить блоки как на предоставленной картинке

Comment: Вы вопрос читали?

Comment: @nosferatu-id сколько блоков было в коде у этого типа, столько и расставил с его техникой тэгов, с помощью CSS. Я думаю остальное он сделает сам.

Comment: @meine Да, читал. Что вы хотите сказать?

Comment: Да. Я хочу сказать вам парни всем. Я делаю задачи так как понимаю их. И если требуется иначе, нужна конкретика. Там где её нет я принимаю собственное решение как это сделать. В данном случае я использовал тэги и цсс вопрошающего. Сколько было блоков, столько сделал. Это пример, полную задачу он решит сам. Я сделал столько блоков, сколько в его коде и сделал так, чтобы картинки вписывались равномерно. Если нужно что-то ещё, то конкретнее. Под смарты, планшеты - медиазапросы пусть использует.

Comment: Второе. Я и сам задавал и периодически задаю вопросы. И даже те люди, которые неправы или не так меня поняли, никому я минусов не ставил. Это неуважение к другим делать подобное, потому что вам тут никто ни чем не обязан.